# What is the difference between "seldom" and "rarely"?

Tags: word-usage, adverbs

I would like to know the difference between **seldom** and **rarely**, Here are some examples:

> I **seldom** play chess.
>
> I **rarely** play chess.

Which ones I've to use and when?

Comment: They are synonymous, which means that they are roughly the same, but not in all cases can you use these words interchangeably. But they have the same meaning, more or less.

Comment: I know, I think "seldom" and "rarely" are like "good","fine" and "nice". Its are synonymous but you can't use "Fine shoes" (It's an example)

Comment: Well, you cannot say *"you **can't** use terms like 'Fine shoes'"*. It may not be used as extensively as _'nice shoes'_, but it's not wrong.

Comment: Why can't you use "fine shoes"?  "Those are some very fine shoes indeed" sounds perfectly normal to me.

Comment: It's ok, but "Good  shoes" is better (I think).

Comment: Fine has an implication when used that way of being acceptable but not much more, unless emphasized the way @stangdon has done. So saying that the shoes are fine, may not have the same interpreted meaning as saying "good".

Comment: @Mattew That's an interesting trio you've picked. "Fine shoes" has the connotation of high quality and workmanship. "Good shoes" has the connotation of effectiveness (keeps feet dry, stays hole-free for a long time, etc). "Nice shoes" has the connotation of pleasant appearance.

Comment: @Lawrence - To the observer, "Nice shoes" connotes appearance. To the wearer, "Nice shoes" could be talking about comfort.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of any example where I would interpret "seldom" and "rarely" differently.

I know "good", "fine", and "nice" sometimes have different meaning based on context.
But "seldom" and "rarely", I can't find any difference.

Comment: Unless you provide detailed explanations with evidence, this post should really be a comment.

Comment: @Max - I have no problem with this answer. While it's true we generally like answers to be substantiated, not every question needs research and a treatise. I've read this answer three times and, concerning the O.P.'s question, it conveys my sentiments exactly. Rarely do synonyms behave so interchangeably, but these two pretty much do.

Comment: *Seldom* has a bit of a more older, smarter mood to it.  I don't hear people say the word *seldom* compared to *rarely* often.  At least in my neck of the woods.  But the actual meaning is not different.